# Android/Web App offline/online Database setup. Creating items on both platforms

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

Read Update 1 for a beter question description. Sorry about that.

I'm trying to figure out how to build a Android App and Web App that syncs there data.
I know that I should make an REST API for the MySQL database to sync with the Android App.
I have made a App before that syncs data but only for retrieval (SELECT queries) on the android side.

I now want to make a Android App / Web App that should create/update items on both platforms and syncs so both have the new/updated items. The app should also work offline.

I'm used to creating id's for most database tables as key with autoincrement. Now that I'll have 2 databases i'm not sure how to create those unique IDs. Or should I ditch those id's and use a combination of columns as primary key (with a timestamp or something).

Hope it makes sence, english is not my native language.

**UPDATE 1**
Narowing the question:
So i have a MySQL database with an PHP API. The API will be used by the Web App and Android App.
Question is how to handle offline data creation in de android App. If you rely on a id with autoincrement of the MySQL Database.

Example: When creating a person how to get an id for that person (If the MySQL database handles ID creation)

Thanks in advance,
Otto Vanluchene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is a very broad question and there's a lot of options, but this is how I do it.

**HOW TO HANDLE NATIVE SIDE REST CALLS:**

First of all I use an HTTP library to handle my GET/POST REST API calls. It handles the callbacks and can be super helpful.

This is the one I usually use:

[**LoopJ's Async HTTP Callback Library**](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

This will handle GET and POST requests with a lot of cool features such as custom timeouts, JSON format, onSuccess() and onFailure() methods, etc. There's a lot of working examples of this library too. I've used it in all my apps and haven't had any problems yet!

**DATABASE SETUP:**

Your going to want to create a MySQL database to store all your data. You may want to read up on common DB practices.

**API SETUP**

I write all my APIs in PHP, but that's just my preference. The APIs you write here will be used in your web AND mobile apps to keep things consistent. Assuming you use GET, you can just pass an argument (which I usually call "callback") that will determine what chunk of information the API will return.

For example:

http://www.ottosite.com/otto_api.php?callback=get_users

So in your PHP code, you'll have it checking if callback=get_users, and if it does, it will query the database for all the users, format the json string, then simply echo it.

This may return something like:

```
{"status":"success","users":["user1","user2","user3"]}
```

So this is obviously a JSON formatted response, then in your app, when you call that API, you just parse the response into a JSONObject (JSONArray for users) and then grab whatever data you need from it.

Hopefully this helps.